# Can Common Data Service / Dataverse data be accessed outside Power Platform?

Tags: powerapps, common-data-service

If I build a PowerApp accessing data from CDS (built from pooling data from couple of other databases), in future can a non-Microsoft application access the data in a CDS? If yes, how?

Would it be an incorrect decision to put reusable data in CDS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDS is more than just a database. It is a platform and provides odata web api, so using that REST endpoints your can access the data from anywhere/everywhere.

PowerApps/Power Automate use the native connector to CDS environment and act as a wrapper for authentication. When you are building other channels like web app, using non-Microsoft technology also - you can access the REST web api. You may need to register the app in Azure Active directory (AAD) for authenticating CDS user account as an extra step.

Comment: can you please give an example for accessing REST web api? This is the one that comes in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api): GET https://org00000000.crm0.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/workflows
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ey... It would be great to see one that works. Thanks!

Comment: @JoseRondon pls find examples - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Arun is correct. If you want a simple API you can also quickly build one in PowerAutomate by using the HTTP trigger and response action.